# Is the wrapper from strcat_s() to strcat() ? If there isn't, is it possible to create one?

Tags: c++, c, string

As the question says it all, Is there any way to create a wrapper for the strcat_s() function? As personally I feel that it is much more difficult to use. Plus why does it return a errno?

I want to make a wrapper which kinda looks like this. Also I don't want to enable _crt_secure_no_warnings

```
void (char* dest, char* src) 
{
    // Execute strcat_s() here
}
```

Samuel

Comment: Why would you need `strcat()` or it's wrapper in C++?

Comment: Just use `std::string`.  No reason to use `strcat` or C99's `strcat_s` in modern C++.

Comment: Because I need to use some particular environment functions like (_dupenv_s)

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you're asking. Create a wrapper that does what?

Comment: Hey @interjay thanks for responding! I edited the question to better explain what I meant.

Comment: But that's the signature of `strcat`. Why don't you just call that? It isn't possible to call `strcat_s` given that signature because you don't know the buffer size.

Comment: Because in VS2017 you need to enable _crt_secure_no_warnings to use the "outdated" functions. Which I do not want to do. Thanks @interjay

Comment: Thankyou! I solved the problem using _dupenv_s() and std::strings @interjay

Comment: Thankyou! I solved the problem using _dupenv_s() and std::strings @Eljay

Comment: Thankyou! I solved the problem using _dupenv_s() and std::strings @Slava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to create a wrapper for the strcat_s() function?

Yes. Define a function. In the function, call `strcat_s`. Now your function is a wrapper for `strcat_s`.

Comment: Thankyou! I solved the problem using _dupenv_s() and std::strings @eerorika

Answer (score -3):

> Is there any way to create a wrapper for the strcat_s() function?

You can't meaningfully create a wrapper function. The Whole reason MS put those warnings/errors there is that the interfaces of the traditional c string handling functions are unsafe by design.

So while sure technically you could write something like.

```
void stupid_strcat(char* dest, char * src)
{
  strcat_s(dest,strlen(dest)+strlen(src)+1,src);
}
```

Doing so would just result in something that was slower than strcat and just as unsafe.

If your destination is a directly accessed (not via a pointer) array then you could write a macro like.

```
#define array_strcat(dest,src) strcat_s(dest,sizeof(dest),src)
```

> As personally I feel that it is much more difficult to use.

Doing C string handling safely is a pain. Generally in C++ you should avoid using C strings and use std::string or similar instead.

> Plus why does it return a errno?

strcat_s can detect certain errors at runtime. When such errors are detected the "constraint handler" is called. If the constraint handler returns then the error will be passed back up to the caller of strcat_s so it knows an error occoured.

Comment: *the traditional c string handling functions are unsafe by design*  [Hogwash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish):  "embrace, extend, and exterminate", is a phrase that the U.S. Department of Justice found that was used internally by Microsoft to describe its strategy for entering product categories involving widely used standards, extending those standards with proprietary capabilities, and then using those differences in order to strongly disadvantage its competitors.

Comment: [To wit](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm):  "A widespread fallacy originated by Microsoft's deprecation of the standard functions in an effort to increase the adoption of the APIs is that every call to the standard functions is necessarily unsafe and should be replaced by one to the "safer" API.

Comment: [It's inherenly multithread-***unsafe***](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm):   "Unfortunately, since there is only one runtime-constraint handler per-process, components that run in distinct threads cannot make use of the set_constraint_handler() function since doing so could change the handler installed and relied on by other threads."

Comment: [They are non-portable](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm):  "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...   As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."